# Can't insert symbols into my matrix

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a matrix written out here, and it appears on the screen fine but I want to put symbols into it. I can't seem to get the symbols (X) to appear in it. Sorry this is my first time working with arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#define WIDTH 70    
#define HEIGHT 20
using namespace std;

void main ()
{
    char world[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
    // draws matrix
    for ( char i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++ ) {
            for ( char j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++ ) {
                world[i][j] = '.';
                cout << world[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
    }
    // 1st symbol at coordinates 1, 1
    int x, y;
    x = 1, y = 1;
    world[x][y] = 'x';
    cout << world[x][y];

    // 2nd symbol at coordinates 2, 2
    x = 2, y = 2;
    world[x][y] = 'x';
    cout << world[x][y];

    //so on..
```

}

Comment: So what *is* happening?

Comment: You can't `cout<<` something and just go back and change it. Did you expect the `'.'` to be replaced by `'x'`? Also, **`void main`**?

Comment: Style notes: It is `int main`, not `void main`; it is better to use `std::vector`; `#define` constants are bad. Also, `x = 1, y = 1;` is rather uncommon and makes not really sense, better just use the semicolon for what it's intended for. Also: It is by far better to use `int` for indexing, not `char`. As soon as you exceed 2<sup>7</sup> for `WIDTH` and/or `HEIGHT` (on 1 char = 8 bit C++ implementations), your code enters implementation-defined behaviour (at least). As soon as it exceeds 2<sup>8</sup>, you enter undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore yea i did :(  ill try and fix it

Answer (score 0):

You have to *first insert* the `x`s, and *then* print the grid, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `main` should be declared as either `int main()` or `int main(int argc, const char* argv[])`; it certainly doesn't return `void`.

The standard output `cout` works sequentially. You just tell it what to print and it does it, one after the other. Consider the following:

```
int x = 1;
std::cout << x;
x = 2;
std::cout << x;
```

Because we changed the value of `x` and then passed it to `cout` again, it seems like you're expecting the output would be:

```
2
```

Actually the output is:

```
12
```

`cout` doesn't care that we passed it the same variable twice. It just prints each thing we give it one after the other.

You're going to have to set each element of the matrix you want to be an `'x'`, then loop through it again and print it all out.